# How to automate direct output from different checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

[Example with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShcOI.png)

I already have the code to extract direct onscreen output after selecting different checkboxes. But I want the output to be categorized with some formatting of the text (see picture): COUNTRY 1/2/3/4 should be on separate lines depending on the checkbox number 1/2/3/4 selected, and if possible I want to remove some of the redundant commas.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='A']").change(function(){
    var checkedCountries = $("input[name='A']:checked");
    var countries = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<checkedCountries.length; i++) {
        countries.push(checkedCountries[i].value + ",");
    }
    $("#countryList").val(countries.join(" "));


});


$("#copyBtn").click(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("countryList");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="mainpage_box"><h3><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="COUNTRY 1:"><span>COUNTRY 1:</span></h3>
<div id="mainpage-admins" title="System administrators" class="items">
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="America">America<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Burma">Burma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="China">China<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Denmark">Denmark<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="England">England<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="France">France<br>
</div></div>

<div class="mainpage_box"><h3><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="COUNTRY 2:"><span>COUNTRY 2:</span></h3>
<div id="mainpage-admins" title="System administrators" class="items">
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="America">America<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Burma">Burma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="China">China<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Denmark">Denmark<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="England">England<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="France">France<br>
</div></div>


<textarea id="countryList" rows="20" cols="150"></textarea></br>
```

The red arrow in the picture show the output screen I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily enough if you add a class to the country category fields then adjust the separator string accordingly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='A']").change(function() {
    var checkedCountries = $("input[name='A']:checked");
    var countries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedCountries.length; i++) {
      // default separator
      let separator = ", ";
      // no comma after category
      if ($(checkedCountries[i]).is('.category')) {
        // EDIT add line break after category
        //separator = " ";
        separator = "\n";
      }
      if (checkedCountries[i + 1] == undefined) {
        // last item needs no separator
        separator = "";
      } else if ($(checkedCountries[i + 1]).is('.category')) {
        // the next item is a category, separate with new line
        separator = "\n";
      }

      // put separator at the end of the value
      countries.push(checkedCountries[i].value + separator);
    }
    // join with null
    $("#countryList").val(countries.join(""));


  });


  $("#copyBtn").click(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("countryList");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainpage_box">
  <h3><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="COUNTRY 1:" class="category"><span>COUNTRY 1:</span></h3>
  <div id="mainpage-admins" title="System administrators" class="items">
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="America">America<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Burma">Burma<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="China">China<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Denmark">Denmark<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="England">England<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="France">France<br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainpage_box">
  <h3><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="COUNTRY 2:" class="category"><span>COUNTRY 2:</span></h3>
  <div id="mainpage-admins" title="System administrators" class="items">
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="America">America<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Burma">Burma<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="China">China<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="Denmark">Denmark<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="England">England<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="France">France<br>
  </div>
</div>


<textarea id="countryList" rows="20" cols="150"></textarea></br>
```

Comment: Dear Arleigh Hix, thank you very much for this beautiful answer, your code works perfectly. If it is not too much trouble, I would also like to know if it is possible to format the categories bold (that is COUNTRY 1, 2, 3 and 4) and to insert a line break after each category, so ex. COUNTRY 1 will stand alone, bold as a headline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dan I edited my answer to insert a line break after each category, but if you want the category bold you need to build an html element instead of a textarea value string. Does that make sense?